# How to add a day to Date field in RTF template for BIP

Tags: rtf, bi-publisher, siebel

I have a small requirement where i have to add +1 day in a given date and then compare it with a different date to fetch a set of records, please make me understand how can this be achieved in BIP (RTF).

something like-

if CompletetdDate+ 1 = ReportedDate , then print "Successful"

Kindly help me.

Thanks,

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe 'xdoxslt:ora_format_date_offset' would help you.
You can see an example in https://help.aconex.com/DisplayContent/advanced-functions-in-the-offline-template-builder.